# Able to save as docx but not pdf

Tags: python, docxtpl

Hi I trying to save all the list as docx and pdf format, i'm able to open the file save as docx but not pdf format. Below my code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


doc = DocxTemplate("sample.docx")
today_date = datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%y")

my_context = {'today_date': today_date}

df = pd.read_excel('list.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     context = {'my_name': row['name'],
                'my_age': row['age']
               }

     context.update(my_context)
     doc.render(context)
     doc.save(f"{row['name']}.docx")
     doc.save(f"{row['name']}.pdf")
```

Comment: DocxTemplate creates docx files. Naming the file `.pdf` won't change the fact that it's still in docx format, not pdf format.

Comment: Oh I see is there a way to save both format at the same time?

Comment: Save a docx and use something like https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/ to convert it to PDF.

Comment: Ahh thanks I tried not sure is it I do not how to code got many error